# Lucene Document creation in while loop slows down more and more

Tags: java, performance, while-loop, lucene, large-data

I have some efficiency problems. I'm developing an enterprise application that is deployed on a jboss EAP 6.1 server as an EAR archive. I create new objects based on entities in a while loop and write them to a file. I get those entities (with help of an EJB DAO) in limited amount (for example 2000 for each step). The problem is that I need to process millions of objects and the first million goes quite smoothly but the further loop goes the slower it works. Can anyone tell me why is this working slower and slower as the loop advances? How can I make it work smoothly all way long? Here are some crucial parts of the code:

```
    public void createFullIndex(int stepSize) {
       int logsNumber = systemLogDao.getSystemLogsNumber();
       int counter = 0;
       while (counter < logsNumber) {
           for (SystemLogEntity systemLogEntity : systemLogDao.getLimitedSystemLogs(counter, stepSize)) {
               addDocument(systemLogEntity);
           }
           counter = counter + stepSize;
       }
       commitIndex();
    }

    public void addDocument(SystemLogEntity systemLogEntity) {
       try {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new NumericField("id", Field.Store.YES, true).setIntValue(systemLogEntity.getId()));
        document.add(new Field("resource", (systemLogEntity.getResource() == null ? "" : systemLogEntity
                .getResource().getResourceCode()), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("operationType", (systemLogEntity.getOperationType() == null ? "" : systemLogEntity
        document.add(new Field("comment",
                (systemLogEntity.getComment() == null ? "" : systemLogEntity.getComment()), Field.Store.YES,
                Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        indexWriter.addDocument(document);
       } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
           LOGGER.error("Failed to add the following log to Lucene index:\n" + systemLogEntity.toString(), e);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           LOGGER.error("Failed to add the following log to Lucene index:\n" + systemLogEntity.toString(), e);
       }
    }
```

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you looked at your heap statistics?

Comment: @HotLicks I thought about it but to be honest I am not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: What is `indexWriter` ? It seems that you are adding all your documents to it, and that it will keep a reference to them, keeping them in memory.

Comment: @FlorentBayle it is an Apache Lucene class. I think I'll try to move commitIndex(); inside the while loop as other people suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you do not write your stuff to file as far as you get it. Instead you try to create full DOM object and then flush it to file. This strategy is good for limited amount of objects. In your case when you have to deal with millions of them (as you said) you should not use DOM. Instead you should be able to create your XML fragments and write them to file while you are receiving the data. This will reduce your memory consumption and hopefully improve the performance.

Comment: I think that was an advice that had the biggest impact. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would try re-using the Document object.  I've had looping issues with the garbage collection where my loops are too fast for the gc to reasonably keep up, and re-use of objects solved all my issues.  I haven't tried re-using the Document object personally, but if it's possible, it may work for you.

Comment: Thank you, that was a reasonable tip! +1

Answer (score 0):

Logging should be easy. Using Guava appending to a text looks like:

```
File to = new File("C:/Logs/log.txt");
CharSequence from = "Your data as string\n";
Files.append(from, to, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Few of my notes :

- I am not sure if your log entities are garbage collected
- It is not clear that file content is kept in memory
- If log is in xml format, then whole XML DOM might need to be parsed if new element is added